# Missing files from a dockerfile and issue with running the docker script

Tags: docker

I was trying to create an image using the docker [this Github repo](https://github.com/shinke-li/Campus3D) using window 10, when I run the script in cmd as instructed according to `readme.md` ,

```
cd docker
docker build -t shinkeli/campus3d:latest .
```

There are some missing archives,

```
> [2/2] RUN apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx:
............
#5 70.56 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-data_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: xxxxx]
#5 70.56 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: xxxxx]
#5 70.56 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-xcb1_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: xxxxxxx]
#5 70.56 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

[Solved] How should I find the missing files to complete the installation?

Another issue,

I now have another issue when I try to run `docker run -it --gpus all -v <path_to_Campus3D>:/root/Campus3D shinkeli/campus3d:latest /bin/bash`.

If let say I saved the repo in `C:\Users\xxx\Campus3D`,
why `docker run -it --gpus all -v C:\Users\xxx\Campus3D:/root/Campus3D shinkeli/campus3d:latest /bin/bash` or `docker run -it --gpus all -v "C:/Users/xxx/Campus3D:/root/Campus3D" shinkeli/campus3d:latest /bin/bash` wont work?

I have installed the NVidia Container Toolkit using Ubuntu following the instruction [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#installing-on-ubuntu-and-debian)

Comment: check with the maintainer of the docker file - the base image using with the apt-get is being run needs a update or upgrade I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As @vbn already said, you need to add

```
RUN apt update
```

or

```
RUN apt-get update
```

Like this:

```yaml
FROM shinkeli/conda-tf2-open3d:v1

MAINTAINER shinkeli

RUN apt update && apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Because the `.deb` file you want to download does not exist anymore:

Your version:

> libx11-data_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2_all.deb

Server version:

[image: archive.ubuntu.com Screenshot]

Edit:

Move `apt update` in the same line as the `apt install command`. Thx to @David Maze, I didn't thought about that.

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get install` need to be in the same `RUN` command.  If they're not, Docker layer caching can cause an old version of the `update` data to be used, which causes the error shown in the question.

Comment: thanks @Spirit and @David Maze! I now have another issue when I try to run `docker run -it --gpus all -v <path_to_Campus3D>:/root/Campus3D shinkeli/campus3d:latest /bin/bash`. If let say I saved the repo in `C:\Users\xxx\Campus3D`, why `docker run -it --gpus all -v C:\Users\xxx\Campus3D:/root/Campus3D shinkeli/campus3d:latest /bin/bash` or `docker run -it --gpus all -v "C:/Users/xxx/Campus3D:/root/Campus3D" shinkeli/campus3d:latest /bin/bash` wont work? thanks!